# how to make an exception for dataweave 2.0 functions skipNullOn and isEmpty()?

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I am trying to figure out how to resolve next issue: I have an array of objects which are pretty similar, but say one of the objects can have additional field. As a result of map function I need to get an array of objects which will contain not null and not empty fields only. For this purpose I am using skipNullOn=everywhere and isEmpty(). And they are working perfectly fine. But I get a new demand for one specific field, let's call it "X" we should have an exception: if this field is null or empty we should return 'false' otherwise 'true'. I can't just remove skipNullOn and isEmpty(), because in this case field "X" will appear in every object where it shouldn't be. Is it possible somehow do an exception for functions skipNullOn and isEmpty()? Please feel free to ask additional questions if I miss something. Any help appreciated.

my input:

```
{
  "data": {
          "array": [
            {
              "A": "A",
              "B": 1,
              "C": "2"
            },
            {
              "A": "A",
              "B": 1,
              "X": "x",
              "C": "2"
            },
            {
              "A": "A",
              "B": 1,
              "C": "2"
            }
          ]
      }
}
```

my current dataweave code:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json skipNullOn = "everywhere"

---
payload.data."array" map (value, index) -> {
    (fieldA: {
        values: [
            value: value.A
        ]
    }) if(!isEmpty(value.A)),
    (fieldB: {
        values: [
            value: value.B
        ]
    }) if(!isEmpty(value.B)),
    (fieldC: {
        values: [
            value: value.C
        ]
    }) if(!isEmpty(value.C)),
    (fieldX: {
        values: [
            value: upper(value.X) == "X"
        ]
    }) if(!isEmpty(value.X))            
}
```

the desired output in case where value of "X" == null or "X" == ""

```
[
  {
    "fieldA": {
      "values": [
        {
          "value": "A"
        }
      ]
    },
    "fieldB": {
      "values": [
        {
          "value": 1
        }
      ]
    },
    "fieldC": {
      "values": [
        {
          "value": "2"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "fieldA": {
      "values": [
        {
          "value": "A"
        }
      ]
    },
    "fieldB": {
      "values": [
        {
          "value": 1
        }
      ]
    },
    "fieldC": {
      "values": [
        {
          "value": "2"
        }
      ]
    },
    "fieldX": {
      "values": [
        {
          "value": false
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "fieldA": {
      "values": [
        {
          "value": "A"
        }
      ]
    },
    "fieldB": {
      "values": [
        {
          "value": 1
        }
      ]
    },
    "fieldC": {
      "values": [
        {
          "value": "2"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: What is your expected output for the input?

Comment: @aled 
for input where "X" == null or "X" == "" the desired output added in code field

Comment: In your input field `X` is not empty nor null, yet it appears in the output as `false`: `"X": "x",`. Please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you both @aled and @jarus, your answers were insightful and helped greatly.
I found that both solutions not fully satisfied me, maybe it is my fault and I have not explained clearly enough. They gave me insights to create a solution that met my demands. The key point was to replace null or empty values in case they are present in the specific field (in this case "X") with boolean 'false' or 'true' if value == "X". I am not claiming that my solution is better or optimal but it resolves my issue.
Once again, really appreciate your help!
Please find below a code:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json 
import * from dw::util::Values
fun checkKey(key) = isEmpty(key) or upper(key) != "X"
fun updateArrValues (array) = array map (value) -> (if (checkKey(value.X)) value  update {
    case .X  -> false
} else if (!checkKey(value.X)) value update {
    case .X -> true
} else value)
---
updateArrValues(payload.data.array)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach for handling this scenario. I hope it helps.

The `skipNullOn = "everywhere"` parameter is not necessary, as the null/empty check is already applied at the field level. The idea here is to apply the null/empty check at the field level and then introduce a new condition to check the key name and apply the appropriate business logic.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload.data.array map ($ mapObject ((value, key, index) -> 
    if(key as String != "X") ("field$(key)":{"values":["value":value]})if(!isEmpty(value)) 
    else ("field$(key)":{"values":["value":if(!isEmpty(value)) true  else false]}))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that @jarus answer has a similar approach to mine. The main difference is that I made it generic and extended it for a potential list of excepted keys. I used a function to encapsulate the logic of the output for each field, without having a fixed key name in the code.

Please find below an example input with different values of "X" and its output.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json 

fun getNotNullEmptyField(keyName, value, exceptedKeyNameList) = do {
    var upperListKeys = exceptedKeyNameList map (upper($))
    var upperKeyName=upper(keyName)
    var newValue=if (upperListKeys contains upperKeyName) (!isEmpty(value)) 
                   else value
    ---
    (("field" ++ keyName): {
        values: [
            value: newValue
        ]
    }) if(!isEmpty(newValue))
}
---
payload.data."array" map (  
    $ mapObject ((value, key, index2) -> 
        getNotNullEmptyField(key as String, value, ["x"])
    )
)
```

Input:

```json
{
  "data": {
          "array": [
            {
              "A": "A",
              "B": 1,
              "C": "2"
            },
            {
              "A": "A",
              "B": 1,
              "X": "x",
              "C": "2"
            },
            {
              "A": "A",
              "B": 1,
              "C": "2",
              "x": null
            }
          ]
      }
}
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "fieldA": {
      "values": [
        {
          "value": "A"
        }
      ]
    },
    "fieldB": {
      "values": [
        {
          "value": 1
        }
      ]
    },
    "fieldC": {
      "values": [
        {
          "value": "2"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "fieldA": {
      "values": [
        {
          "value": "A"
        }
      ]
    },
    "fieldB": {
      "values": [
        {
          "value": 1
        }
      ]
    },
    "fieldX": {
      "values": [
        {
          "value": true
        }
      ]
    },
    "fieldC": {
      "values": [
        {
          "value": "2"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "fieldA": {
      "values": [
        {
          "value": "A"
        }
      ]
    },
    "fieldB": {
      "values": [
        {
          "value": 1
        }
      ]
    },
    "fieldC": {
      "values": [
        {
          "value": "2"
        }
      ]
    },
    "fieldx": {
      "values": [
        {
          "value": false
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```